# Rendering view using ViewModel or JSON object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

My searching failed to find what I thought would be a well travelled subject. My options outlined at the bottom reflect some things I found.

I need to render a view from the server side as a ViewModel or via a JSON object. The JSON object would come from server.

On client side I use ajax and sometimes I determine insertion based on other id/attributes on the page as to whether I append/prepend/replace or ignore-placing to the target element.

**What options do I have to use the same view for ViewModels or JSON objects?**

I had considered, on compile, render a File.Js version of the view. Include that as a resource on the page and perform replaces on the `var ViewHtmlTemplate = "<div>@Model.Message</div>`. I would have to be very disciplined in moving all formatting/if-statement logic to the viewmodel which would also be JSON serialized.

Or, that the view has a script tag to bind the ViewModel serilized to a js var and then run a function on document ready.

The 3rd option is instead of returning a JSON object, to return an array of serverside already html-rendered views.

Comment: you can use other methods like `JQuery.load`. otherwise use a JQuery Ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the solution which returns the Html in the json object. If there are any problems with doing that please let me know. Here is how I went about it.

**Controller extension to render partial a view** (included but not used in this solution is RenderViewToString). This can be found in various forms across different answers which did not seem to match my customized version which I do not take credit for.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    using System.IO;

    public static class MvcControllerExtension
    {
        public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName = null, object model = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            {
                viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            }

            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }

        public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName = null, object model = null, string masterName = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            {
                viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            }

            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, masterName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In the controller action returning JsonResult**

```
public JsonResult _DisplayByFoo(int catId)
{
    var myRealModel = new MyRealModel(catId);
    // .... omitted the construction of MyRealModel
    var jsonModel = new JsonModel(myRealModel);
    jsonModel.Html = this.RenderPartialViewToString("_Display", myRealModel);
    return Json(jsonModel);
}
```

*I also include other properties on the json object which help me determine my insertion mode.*

**In Js;** after my AjaxCall to the Json action. Run OnSuccess method, which, apart from other logic, does the following.

```
$("#" + targetId).append(MyJson.Html);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is inside of my view model I will have a field which is a string which is a serialized json structure.

```
public class SomeVM
{
 /* other properties */
 public string jsonString { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I will serialize some data into the jsonString. Then in the view, I will assign the string to a variable

```
@model SomeVM
<script>
 var jsonVM = @( Html.Raw(Model.jsonString) );
</script>
```